# Как в IIS сервере настроить прием данных от клиента?

Tags: backend, iis, iis-10

Сервер отображает сайт, всё окей, а вот где мне backend настроить — я не знаю.

В node.js просто свой сервер. То есть я даже не знаю, куда мне отсылать запрос, на какой URL.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Прежде чем задать вопрос, загугли его на другом языке - например, английском ;) Тут дали ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472429/how-do-i-configure-iis-to-accept-post-requests А тут подробнее:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/

Answer (score -1):

Надеюсь понял всё правильно. Вам нужно открыть "Диспетчер служб IIS".
Клавиши: Win+R и введите inetMgr, после чего нажимите Enter.